# Получить строки используя регулярные выражения из txt JAVA

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Eсть `txt` фаил (в котором хранятся версии установленных обновлений ПО) мне нужно как то получить самую последнюю версию
вот пример ---->

> 30.11.2020 Обновление 2.218.2.218
> 27.11.2020 Обновление 2.217.2.217
> 20.11.2020 Обновление 2.216.2.216

насколько я понял регулярка должна выглядеть вот так `(\d{1}\.\d{3}\.\d{1}\.\d{3})`
а вот как пройтись по всему документу непонятно

```
 List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("\"D:\\d\\Readme.txt\""));

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1}\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{3}");

for (String read : lines) {
    
                }
```

Comment: Наверное, `"(?s)(?<!\\d|\\d\\.)(?:\\d\\.\\d{3}){2}(?!\\.?\\d)(?!.*(?<!\\d|\\d\\.)(?:\\d\\.\\d{3}){2}(?!\\.?\\d))"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вот так решил

data.txt

> ```
> 30.11.2020 Обновление 2.218.2.218
> 27.11.2020 Обновление 2.217.2.217
> 20.11.2020 Обновление 2.216.2.216
> ```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C:/data.txt");

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
      String line;
      String fullText = "";
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        fullText += line;
      }
      final String sourceText = fullText;
      Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1}\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{3})").matcher(sourceText);
      List<String> matchedResults =
          matcher
              .results()
              .map(result -> sourceText.substring(result.start(), result.end()))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println(matchedResults);
    }
  }
```

выхлоп такой

```
[2.218.2.218, 2.217.2.217, 2.216.2.216]
```

ну или под ваш вариант

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\data.txt"));

    final String sourceText = lines.stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1}\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{3})").matcher(sourceText);
    List<String> matchedResults =
        matcher
            .results()
            .map(result -> sourceText.substring(result.start(), result.end()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(matchedResults);
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное) если вас не затруднит оставьте пожалуйста пару комментариев чтобы понимать как оно работает))

Comment: Тут в основном Stream Api. остальное так себе